# Json request body not handled by NestJs

Tags: javascript, json, post, nestjs, httprequest

I've implemented a NestJs controller and then a facade service that listens to POST requests and after the request arrives, it does some operations.

Now, it works for "text/plain" content-type, but not for "application/json" content-type.
The body is exactly the same.

This is the method in the controller:

```
  @Public()
  @Post(SERVER_COVID_A_CASA_CARE_PLAN_NOTIFICATION_PATH)
  getNotification(@Req() request: Request, @Res() response: Response) {
    this.facade.manageCarePlanNotification(request, response);
  }
```

This is the method in the facade service:

```
manageCarePlanNotification(request: Request, response: Response) {
    let jsonBodyReq = '';

    request.on('data', function (data) {
      jsonBodyReq += data;
    });

    request.on('end', () => {
      this.manageCarePlanNotificationRequest(jsonBodyReq, response);
    });

    request.on('error', function (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    });
  }
```

The request in json arrives to the controller, arrives to the manageCarePlanNotification method, but does not reach the on(data) event, which is correctly reached by the text/plain request (same happens in the on (end) event).

Any help will be really appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What for inventing the wheel again?

NestJS is there to take req/res from your back. It abstracts req/res, so first of all it is platform agnostic (Express/Fastify) and also you don't have to care about handling it and getting into troubles as you exactly did.

When you're using Nest, you suppose to simply use `@Body data: YourDataTypeInJSON` and just do sth like:

```js
  @Public()
  @Post(SERVER_COVID_A_CASA_CARE_PLAN_NOTIFICATION_PATH)
  getNotification(@Body() data: IDontKnowYourDataType) {
    return this.facade.manageCarePlanNotificationRequest(data);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm learning NestJs on my own and I've found this logic in various tutorial, so you're right now it works with json.

Comment: I am happy that it worked for you!

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz Can you answer this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928790/request-body-is-not-parsed-as-json-in-nestjs